# How to select column in web api using LINQ

Tags: linq

I'm really a newbie in ASP.NET, I have a table consists of 4 columns, id, name, address, and phone. I'd like to do a query select id, name from table x but I have no idea how to write it using LINQ in ASP.NET web API

```
public class rateperjamallController : ApiController
{     
    public double GET()
    {            
        TeamDataContext db1 = new TeamDataContext();
        var item = db1.Teams.Select(c => c);
        var id = item.Select(a => a.id);
        return id;}

  }
```

}

Does anyone have any idea to help me since I am really a newbie?

Comment: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/LINQ-to-DataSets-09787825

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking fora specific record in the dataset? If yes, you need to pass the id or name and create a query for that. For example, this is what you can do: (if you pass id as a parameter)

```
public class rateperjamallController : ApiController
{     
    public double GET(string id)
    {            
        TeamDataContext db1 = new TeamDataContext();
        return db1.Teams.Where(x => x.id == id)?.First();
  }
}
```